# Apache Airflow: Fetching remote s3 logs fails: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, boto3, amazon-iam

**Apache Airflow version**: 2.1.2

**Environment**:

- **Cloud provider or hardware configuration**: AWS ECS Fargate

**What happened**:

I have made an update from 2.0.1 to 2.1.2, and fetching the logs from s3 fails suddenly:
`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::111111111:assumed-role/airflow-ecs-task-role/cfdjkal342nk432hvbkjl34 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/airflow-ecs-task-role`

I am wondering why the ecs task itself is not able to assume its own role? Isn´t that what it basically means?

**What you expected to happen**:

Getting the logs from remote s3 as before.

**Anything else we need to know**:
All Fargate tasks (webserver, scheduler, worker) are getting the following environment variables. I have followed [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#generating-a-connection-uri)  approach to generate the connection URI.

```
- Name: AIRFLOW_CONN_LOGS_S3
  Value: !Sub 's3://s3?aws_account_id=111111111&role_arn=arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A919107267526%3Arole%2Fairflow-ecs-task-role'
- Name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING
  Value: 'true'
- Name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER
  Value: !Sub "s3://logs-bucket/"
- Name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID
  Value: logs_s3
- Name: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__ENCRYPT_S3_LOGS
  Value: 'false'
```

How often does this problem occur? Once? Every time etc?

Any relevant logs to include? Put them here in side a detail tag:

```
*** Failed to verify remote log exists s3://bucket/dag/dag/2021-07-23T11:37:30.860418+00:00/1.log.
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::111111111:assumed-role/airflow-ecs-task-role/cfdjkal342nk432hvbkjl34 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/airflow-ecs-task-role
*** Falling back to local log
*** Log file does not exist:
```

I do have the following attached to the airflow-ecs-task-role:

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
  Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

If I add this, it works though:

```
 Principal:
      Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
      AWS: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/airflow-ecs-task-role/TASK_ID
```

Can someone help why that is the case? The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#:%7E:text=you%20cannot%20use%20a%20wildcard%20(*)%20to%20mean%20%22all%20sessions%22.%20Principals%20must%20always%20name%20a%20specific%20session.) state that I cannot wildcard that, but I do not know the task ID beforehand.

Comment: I am desperately asking if you ever got this fixed and how you did it? I have ran into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the task role as a principal resolved the issue:

```
Resources:
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-ecs-execution-role-${Stage}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
              AWS: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/airflow-ecs-task-role-${Stage}
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMReadOnlyAccess'
```